Handing OAuth2 refresh token race conditions
We're implementing a 'BFF' (Backend for Frontend) pattern for our application, which is a recommendation from the draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps.
One complication we're running into is handing OAuth2 refresh. It's not uncommon for us to have 2 request running almost in parallel. If the access token in this case is expired, they might both try to initiate a refresh, which means the first request wins.
There's a few ways to address this:

Optimistically refresh the token before it expires. The issue with this is that we need to maintain a ton of state for every active session.
Creating a locking system. Not super easy when assuming there's multiple instances of a backend.
Loosen the single-use requirement of the refresh token, so multiple parallel requests can all succeed. This feels somewhat dangerous.

I'm curious if there's any known best practices around this

I always handle this client-side, where it is common to lay out a tree of views that call APIs concurrently. Concurrent refresh is easiest to handle client side.
The BFF can provide an endpoint like this that enables token refresh, though the JavaScript app decides when to call it:

POST /refresh

This leads to code that calls APIs behaving like this
let response = await callApi(options);
if (response.status === 401)
    await synchronizedRefresh():
    response = await callApi(options);
}

The synchronizedRefresh method is fairly easy to write by queueing up a collection of promises. But only actually call the refresh endpoint for the first view. When the refresh completes, you can then resolve all promises with the same result.
